# Template compare operator

Tags: c++, templates

I have a following template class:

```
template<int size, typename Type>
class Matrix {
    public:
        Matrix();
        ...
        Type operator ()(int row, int column) {...}
    private:
        std::array<Type, size*size> _array;
}
```

And I want to overload `equal to` comparison operator to compare `Matrix` objects:

```
template <int size, typename LeftType, typename RightType>
bool operator ==(const Matrix<size, LeftType> & left, const Matrix<size, RightType> & right) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that comparison of integer types and real types is quite different:

`real case`:

```
template <int size, typename LeftType, typename RightType>
bool operator ==(const Matrix<size, LeftType> & left, const Matrix<size, RightType> & right) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (qFuzzyIsNull(left(i, j)) || qFuzzyIsNull(right(i, j))) {
                if (!qFuzzyCompare(left(i, j) + 1, right(i, j) + 1)) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (!qFuzzyCompare(left(i, j), right(i, j))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

(I'm using Qt's [qFuzzyCompare](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qFuzzyCompare) and [qFuzzyIsNull](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qFuzzyIsNull))

`integer case`:

```
template <int size, typename LeftType, typename RightType>
bool operator ==(const Matrix<size, LeftType> & left, const Matrix<size, RightType> & right) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (left(i, j) != right(i, j)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

How to enable `integer case` if both `LeftType` and `RightType` integer and enable `real case` if at least one `LeftType` or `RightType` is real?

Comment: Overload `!=` for the `real type` so you can use the same function for both?

Comment: You could use template specialization and write one version escpacally for LeftType and RightType = int. Therefore that special function will always be called if both are integer. One also could think of adding explicit for that case, if a conversion is not wished for.

Comment: `template specialization` is what you are looking for. But @NathanOliver is right, the logic (nested for loop) is the same, and it may be better to overload operator != for the real type.

Comment: Yes it kind of solution. But in this case I should specialize each real type (float, double, long double). It isn't big problem, but maybe it is possible to use another method?

Comment: And maybe someone will give a little pice of code about how to do what @NathanOliver suggests?

Comment: @KamilZaripov it's hard to tell how you recognize an integer from a real case, but probably something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b432b3e8de2df89) should work

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thank you.

Comment: BTW, considering that your private member is 1d array, you don't need two nested loops, one is enough, and [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) is even better.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
template <int size, typename LeftType, typename RightType>
bool operator ==(const Matrix<size, LeftType> & left, const    Matrix<size,    RightType> & right) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (not is_equal(left(i,j), right(i,j)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and then you either define several overloaded variants of is_equal or make is_equal a template and define it's specializations, like

```
template<class T> 
bool is_equal(const T a, const T b);

template<>
bool is_equal<int>(const int a, const int b){
    return a == b;
}

template<>
bool is_equal<real>(const real a, const real b){
    ...
}
```

(or as a template over two types if that can happen)

You could, of course, specialize the operator itself, but that means that you have to write the same code all over again without any chance that you will reuse it. Meanwhile, is_equal could become some common tool in your program.

(note: is_equal is a somewhat basic name, so it should be in a namespace, obviously)